# Errors encountered while processing "key-mapper"

Tags: 20.04, sudo, vulkan

I'm trying to set up vulkan on my Ubuntu VM (running on MacOS Big Sur 11.3.1) and I keep getting this error when running "sudo apt install vulkan-tools".

Here's the entire log:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vulkan-tools is already the newest version(1.2.131.1+dfsg1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up key-mapper (1.0.0) ...
Failed to enable unit: Unit file key-mapper.service does not exist.
Failed to start key-mapper.service: Unit key-mapper.service not found.
dpkg: error processing package key-mapper (--configure):
 installed key-mapper package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 key-mapper
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone has any idea what this means? I couldn't find much on google.

Comment: Woops, had put the wrong version of Ubuntu. It is updated now

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy key-mapper` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04.

I think the key mapper is not related with what we were trying to do, so I just uninstalled it and problem solved. Key mapper is something I installed a while ago, and never really used it anyway.

```
$ sudo apt remove input-remapper  
$ sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```